# How do I implement initial page load animations?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, next.js

[image]How do I implement initial page load animations, bunch of blocks in gray color with loading animation till the actual content renders in Next Js. I there any library for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With React 18, use the `React.Suspense` API to get to a fallback

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactsuspense

```
// This component is loaded dynamically
const OtherComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./OtherComponent'));

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    // Displays <Spinner> until OtherComponent loads
    <React.Suspense fallback={<Spinner />}>
      <div>
        <OtherComponent />
      </div>
    </React.Suspense>
  );
}
```

Where spinner could be a component that is built from a great resource like this

https://skeletonreact.com/

### More Options

https://github.com/buildo/react-placeholder

Comment: You can't imagine how much helpful it was. Thank you so much